# What is a good transfer speed for a USB2.0 Flash Drive?

Tags: performance, usb-flash-drive

Transfer speed of flash drives seems to vary significantly.  What do people see as the minimum acceptable performance (read / write in MB/sec)?  What would constitute really good performance?

Comment: Would also love an answer to this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jeff Atwood wrote a nice post on Coding Horror about [large USB flash drive performances](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/06/large-usb-flash-drive-performance.html). I recommend you read the full article. Below is an excerpt:

> Modern 2.5" hard drive performance
>   looks something like this:
>
> HDD Sequential Read   55 MB/sec   HDD
>   Sequential Write  55 MB/sec
>
> But what about large USB flash drives?
>   How do they compare to typical hard
>   drive speeds, much less the
>   awe-inspiring Velociraptor? X-Bit Labs
>   recently reviewed three 32 GB USB
>   flash drives:
>
> Type - Sequential Read - Sequential Write
>   32 GB Corsair Flash Voyager - 22 MB/sec - 10 MB/sec
>   32 GB OCZ Rally 2 - 30 MB/sec - 22 MB/sec
>   32 GB Patriot Xporter XT - 31 MB/sec - 17 MB/sec

Answer (score 3):

This doesn't answer the question of what people see as minimum acceptable performance, but there are [some good charts at tom's hardware](http://www.tomshardware.com/charts/usb-thumb-drive-charts/benchmarks,109.html).

Comment: It does allow you to gauge what might be seen as top end and bottom end though.  It seems if you're not getting at least 20/10 then you're being short changed.